# Delete Mail With Large Attachments From Outbox

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Using Outlook 2019 and Windows 10.  Tried to send an email with with a 14 MByte attachment.  Mail was not sent and shows up in Outbox Folder.

Outlook then set to Work Offline.  Attempts to delete email included:

- Highlight email and press Delete button
- Right click on email and select delete.
- Highlight email and select delete icon from Outlook menu
- Right click folder and select Delete All.  In this case, I receive a confirmation dialogue, but the mail does not get deleted.
- Right click on email and select Move/Drafts.  Mail does not get moved.
- Attempt to open mail and remove attachment.  Result shown below.

[image: Error message when attempting to open email]

I also restarted not only Outlook, but Windows, and tried all that again with the same results.  I also tried running Outlook in Safe Mode, but no joy.

Finally, I tried the web interface provided by my ISP, but that does not show an Outbox folder.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: What type of email account is this connected to? Exchange; pop3; imap? Sounds like this is a corrupt PST file.  Here is more information: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repair-outlook-data-files-pst-and-ost-25663bc3-11ec-4412-86c4-60458afc5253

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying a variety of things, I succeeded as follows.

- Switch from Working Offline to Connected
- Initiate Send/Receive (F9 key)
- Cancel the send task from the Send/Receive dialogue.
- Highlight the email and delete it with the Delete key.

I don't know how or why this method succeeded, I know only that it did.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to try creating a [new temporary default pst file](https://www.howto-outlook.com/faq/messagestuckinoutbox.htm):

> 1. Create a new pst-file: **Ribbon tab: Home-> button: New Items-> More Items-> Outlook Data File**
> 2. Set this pst-file as the default data file in your Account Settings: **File-> Account Settings-> Account Settings-> tab Data
>      Files**
> 3. When you now restart Outlook, your original pst-file will show up as the secondary set of mailbox folders. From here, you should be able
>      to move the message from the Outbox folder or even delete the entire
>      Outbox folder (when you do, make sure you also delete it from the
>      Deleted Items folder or hold the SHIFT button when deleting the folder
>      to bypass the Deleted Items folder).
> 4. Set the original pst-file as the default delivery location again via the same method as above and restart Outlook. If you deleted the
>      Outbox folder, it will automatically be recreated and will be empty

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  Regrettably, when I got to Step 3, I got the same results as before.  It was worth a shot though.